# Run time analysis of Dijkstra's algorithm, I am getting O(Vlog(V) + VE)

Tags: time-complexity, dijkstra

I am trying to determine the run time of dijkstra's algorithm using
min-priority queue (which is implemented using a Fibonacci heap)

The code
[image]

Analysis:
I know that for Fibonacci heap insert is Decrease/Insert Key is O(1) and to extract min it's O(log(n))

Line 1 to 3: The run time is O(V), for every vertex

The loop in line 4 takes O(V), but the ExtractMin takes O(log(V)),
also the for loop from line 6-7 its O(E), for every edge

There for since the for loop is within the while loop,
I would have V(log(V) + E)

so I would get O(V + V*log(V) + V*E) which comes down to O( V*log(V) + V*E)

but most of the articles indicate it is  O( V*log(V) + E), is it because E>V or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each vertex will get pulled out by ExtractMin at most once, so that the inner for loop (across all iterations of the while loop) will select each edge at most once; hence the E, and not V*E, term.